# SQL Query returning different results on same Oracle database on 2 different systems

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have a 2 identical databases running on Oracle 12c. They are sitting on 2 different servers.

I'm executing the following query using SQL Developer on both databases.

```
select *
from sla
where objectname = 'INCIDENT' and
      status in 'ACTIVE'  and
      (exists (select 1
               from classancestor
               where ancestor=sla.classstructureid and classancestor.classstructureid= '')  or
       classstructureid is null or
       classstructureid =  ''
      ) ;
```

I get 260 results on one of the databases and 0 results on the other. This query is generated by an ERP we are using so I cannot modify the SQL itself.

One thing I noticed is that if I remove the parentheses surrounding the exists operator, the behaviour changes.

Can someone help? Is there a precedence when using OR? Is there an Oracle patch that has an impact on how SQL statements are processed?

Thanks

Comment: `the behaviour changes` ... _how_ does the behavior change?  My guess is that the underlying tables are not the same.

Comment: Yes sorry, I get the same result on both databases. Both databases are identical, each table present in the SQL statement was compared thoroughly

Comment: Next question: Are both databases running the same version of Oracle?

Comment: YES Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
"CORE 12.1.0.2.0 Production"
TNS for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production

Comment: I can't explain this, but could you update your question with the logic behind the `WHERE` clause?  I am assuming there is some funky precedence stuff going on here, but if you write your query right, that shouldn't matter on any version or Oracle.

Comment: Yes I totally agree Tim, unfortunately this query is generated from java code. On the other hand, I would expect both systems to return the same result.

Comment: Gordon, why is "Status in 'ACTIVE'" not valid SQL? I'm not saying it's optimal, but in this case it will surely return the same results as Status='ACTIVE'

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, `status in 'ACTIVE'` works fine in Oracle, please see this demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/68e87/3

Comment: @krokodilko . . . That is really strange, but I removed my comment.

Comment: Since `classstructureid = ''` will never be true, I would expect the only rows you get back would be the ones where `sla.classstructureid is null`. Is that what you are seeing?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, for now I simply reverted to Oracle 11g optimizer and solved my issue.

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET optimizer_features_enable='11.2.0.3';
```

Not my favorite solution, but it's a workaround for now.

Thanks for your help guys